# How can i seperately change the workspace on my two screens?

Tags: multiple-monitors, screen, workspaces

I have two different screens, one FullHD and one HDready and i often have openend many windows. To manage these, the Ubuntu workspaces do a good job, but it would be excellent if it could be changed seperately, so that i can have the windows on the right that are used less often but need a look on and those on the left that are needed to change often.
So i could have 8 workspaces and seperately choose one for every monitor. Is there anything like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gnome-Shell does this. If you are ok with using something non-unity, the right screen can switch desktops while the left does not (for me), although I am sure this is configurable.

[image]

This is my right monitor, while this

[image]

is both my monitors. Notice there is no workspace switcher on the left monitor.

(The workspace switcher is on the very right; it is minimized in the picture.)

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm using Gnome3 now too. It's way better IMO. Thx!